# GraphQL official learn section Interfaces - raises cannot query field “totalCredits” on type “Human”

Tags: graphql

Just starting to learn GraphQL and probably making silly mistake.

On https://graphql.org/learn/schema/#interfaces they have the two below interfaces;

```
type Human implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  starships: [Starship]
  totalCredits: Int
}

type Droid implements Character {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  friends: [Character]
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  primaryFunction: String
}
```

the below works fine

```
query HeroForEpisode($ep: Episode!) {
  hero(episode: $ep) {
    name
    ... on Droid {
        primaryFunction
    }
    ... on Human {
      starships {
        name
      }
    }
  }
}
```

but if I try totalCredits;

```
query HeroForEpisode($ep: Episode!) {
  hero(episode: $ep) {
    name
    ... on Droid {
        primaryFunction
    }
    ... on Human {
        totalCredits
    }
  }
}
```

[image: screen shot of error]

it error with;

```
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Cannot query field \"totalCredits\" on type \"Human\".",
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 8,
          "column": 4
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

What mistake am I making or is it not me?

Cheers in advance

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt their documentation website has bugs or confusing.

This is the [code repository](https://github.com/graphql/graphql.github.io) of the website. From the [source codes](https://github.com/graphql/graphql.github.io/blob/4a919d3a0d009976797ce42e95432cee134e10c3/src/components/Marked/swapiSchema.tsx#L86), the `Human` schema actually is :

```
# A humanoid creature from the Star Wars universe
type Human implements Character {
  
  # The ID of the human
  id: ID!

  # What this human calls themselves
  name: String!

  # Height in the preferred unit, default is meters
  height(unit: LengthUnit = METER): Float
 
  # Mass in kilograms, or null if unknown
  mass: Float
  
  # This human's friends, or an empty list if they have none
  friends: [Character]
  
  # The friends of the human exposed as a connection with edges
  friendsConnection(first: Int, after: ID): FriendsConnection!
  
  # The movies this human appears in
  appearsIn: [Episode]!
  
  # A list of starships this person has piloted, or an empty list if none
  starships: [Starship]
}
```

It only has fields called `height` and `mass` but no fields called `totalCredits`. You can also verify it from the auto-suggest feature of that GraphQL query editor by clicking <kbd>Ctrl + Space</kbd> after typing  `... on Human {`

[image]

You can also consider to report this issue to them at [here](https://github.com/graphql/graphql.github.io/issues) telling that it is confusing for you to learn.